# Flutter ListTile (tileColor) conditionally

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible change tileColor eg.  if _userDetails[index].salary < 1000 Colors.red else Color.blue or maybe return color from query and set **tileColor: _userDetails[index].color,**

```
title: Text(_userDetails[index].name),
subtitle: Text(_userDetails[index].salary.toString()),
tileColor: Colors.red,
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```dart
tileColor: _userDetails[index].salary < 1000  ? Colors.red : Colors.blue
```